# Storing AuthLogin and AuthPassword on Android

Tags: android, authentication, acra

I am using Acrarium-Acra to collect debug logs for customer facing issues in my Android App. Acrarium generates a unique AuthLogin and AuthPassword pair for the application.

```
httpSender {
    uri = "/report" /*best guess, you may need to adjust this*/
    basicAuthLogin = "GvDez9x0JyhdzyXR"
    basicAuthPassword = "wWg1bbKYtciU7Yqs"
    httpMethod = HttpSender.Method.POST
}
```

I don't think it is safe to store the AuthLogin and AuthPassword as hard coded strings in my application. Are there any recommendations on storing these values?

Comment: relevant discussion: https://github.com/ACRA/acra/issues/1002

Answer (score 0):

How about `EncryptedSharedPreferences`? It can encrypts keys and values.

[Work with data more securely](https://developer.android.google.cn/topic/security/data)

Wraps the SharedPreferences class and automatically encrypts keys and values using a two-scheme method:

**Keys** are encrypted using a deterministic encryption algorithm such that the key can be encrypted and properly looked up.
**Values** are encrypted using AES-256 GCM and are non-deterministic.

Comment: Thanks @Krahmal. How do I get the data to the application for the first time.

Comment: @Vishvesh "get the data to the application for the first time"--Do you mean default value?